# order by 2 columns with sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to order by names however the creator should be listed first so I wrote the below and got the error

> 1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set

How do I write this so the creator is the first result? I don't understand why I have this error. My query is

```
select u.id as id, u.name as name, 0 as creator from User u 
join Moderator m on m.forumID=@forumID and m.userID=u.id 
union 
select u.id, u.name, f.creator as creator from User u 
join Forum f on f.id=@forumID and u.id=w.creator 
order by creator<>0, u.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select u.id as id, u.name as name, 0 as creator from User u 
join Moderator m on m.forumID=@forumID and m.userID=u.id 
union 
select u.id, u.name, f.creator from User u 
join Forum f on f.id=@forumID and u.id=w.creator 
order by creator, name
```

In an union, the first query gives the column names, the following queries only have to return matched column type values, their names is not important.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use alias name `creator` in the `WHERE`, `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`statements.

Use number of column in your case:

```
SELECT ....
ORDER BY 3, 2
```

this is not good practice but it works in your  question...

Comment: Great this works, but why isn't it good practice? Could you give me the short or one sentence version?

Comment: I think this is because it is a _hard-coding_. When later you or your colleague will need to change query(add columns or something else) then it easy to forget updating of numbers in `ORDER BY`

Comment: That's why I wanted to do it by name. Do you suggest doing something else?